# Copy information from form sheet and input into corresponding sheet based on Month and date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loRAS8It7iTU8C00UDsFe1dCIweT7hl_qKE5Y6bKUZ8/edit?usp=sharing) to track bookings, one month per sheet. I have a form submission page which has the day, month, year and name for bookings.

I would like to:

1. Find the name of the booking (`Sheet2, Column D`)
2. Find the sheet with the matching month (`Sheet 2, Column B`)

The code for the above 2 points looks like this:

```
    var currentRow = sheet2.getLastRow();
    var day = sheet2.getRange(currentRow, 1).getValue();
    var month = sheet2.getRange(currentRow, 2).getValue();
    var course = sheet2.getRange(currentRow, 4).getValue();

    var monthSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(month);
```

3. In that sheet, find the corresponding date number
4. Get the cell underneath the relevant date
5. Input booking name.

For example, JB has booked for the 12th June 2024. In the sheet called `June` the 12th is in cell `D8` and there is an empty box in `D9` where I want to input JB.

Sheet 2 looks like this:

| Day | Month | Year | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | June | 2024 | JB |

Sheet called "June" looks like this:

| MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
|  | HI |  |  |  |  |  |
| 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

When run, it keeps returning the log, *`Could not find the specified day (12) in the June sheet`*

The remaining points code is below. I'm assuming there are a whole bunch of errors. Any help would be amazing.

```
if (monthSheet) {
      // Find the day in the selected month sheet
      var dayColumn = findColumnByValue(monthSheet, 1, day)

      if (dayColumn !== -1) {
        // Input data into the cell below the specified day
        var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        var dateRow = monthSheet.getRange(2, dayColumn, monthSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
        var rowIndex = dateRow.flat().indexOf(today) + 2;

        if (rowIndex !== -1) {
          // Input data into the cell below the specified day
          monthSheet.getRange(rowIndex, dayColumn).setValue(course);

          Logger.log('Data input successful on ' + today + ' for ' + day + ' in ' + month + '.');
        } else {
          Logger.log("Could not find today's date (" + today + ') in the ' + month + ' sheet.');
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log("Could not find the specified day (" + day + ') in the ' + month + ' sheet.');
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log("Could not find the sheet for the specified month (" + month + ').');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('An error occurred: ' + e);
  }
}

function findColumnByValue(sheet, column, value) {
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === value) {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1; // Not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a few modifications but I did not test it.

```
function inputMonthlyData() {
  try {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    const cr = sh2.getActiveCell().getRow();
    const dt = new Date();
    const mA = [...new Array(12).keys()].map(idx => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),idx,15),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MMMM"));
    var monthSheet = ss.getSheetByName(mA[dt.getMonth()]);
    if (monthSheet) {
      var dayColumn = dt.getMonth() + 1;
      if (dayColumn !== -1) {
        var today = Utilities.formatDate(dt, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        var dateRow = monthSheet.getRange(2, dayColumn, monthSheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
        var rowIndex = dateRow.flat().indexOf(today) + 2;

        if (rowIndex !== -1) {
          // Input data into the cell below the specified day
          monthSheet.getRange(rowIndex, dayColumn).setValue(course);

          Logger.log('Data input successful on ' + today + ' for ' + day + ' in ' + month + '.');
        } else {
          Logger.log("Could not find today's date (" + today + ') in the ' + month + ' sheet.');
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log("Could not find the specified day (" + day + ') in the ' + month + ' sheet.');
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log("Could not find the sheet for the specified month (" + month + ').');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('An error occurred: ' + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, unfortunately this doesn't work. Initially issues with the formatDate string but then it is successful but nothing happens.

Comment: I've made some edits, any further ideas now?

Comment: Like I said I did not  test it so you are going to have to be a little more precise in your description of the problem.  Possibly it might be useful to provide a table of data. - [How to make a data table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/206484)

Comment: Thanks again, didn't know you could make data tables. I have rewritten my question, hopefully makes more sense now.